# Which tags are counted in form.elements?

Tags: javascript, html

What tag is counted in `form.elements`?

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>
          form process
      </title>
      <script>
          function showelements()
          {
              var form = document.getElementById("f");
              var n = form.elements.length;
              alert(n);
          }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
         <form id="f" action="#" method="post">
            <p>Hello</p>
            <input type="text" />
            <input type="text" />
            <button onclick="showelements()">Click</button>
        </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

I think `n = 4` because there are 4 elements: `p`, `input`, `input`, `button`, but the result `n = 3`.

Answer (score 5):

The elements collection contains only *form controls* (input, select, button, textarea and fieldset).

If you want all the elements in the form, use `frm.getElementsByTagName("*")`.

Comment: A link to some official documentation would be helpful.

Comment: @zsawyer — It would, but while I can find a number of specs saying "form controls", I haven't been able to find one which defines that term, so they aren't very useful.

Comment: thank you, but why <input type="image" src="" /> is not counted?

Comment: I have no idea. It seems to be a pretty poorly defined part of the specification.

Comment: On the other hand [w3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_form_elements.asp) states _"The elements collection returns an array of all the elements in a form."_ and _"The Element object represents an element in the HTML document."_ (for [element](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_element.asp)) While your statement is empirically correct it might just be browser specific behavior?

Comment: @zsawyer — You are linking to W3Schools, not the W3C. W3Schools are awful, often wrong and give some very, very dangerous advice.

Comment: The actual spec can be found here: http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/html.html#ID-76728479 (but as I said, I can't find a definition of "form control elements")

Answer (score 1):

Ok this time from W3C: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-form-elements

> The `elements` IDL attribute must return an [`HTMLFormControlsCollection`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#htmlformcontrolscollection-0) [...]

Here is a [more comprehensive list](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#category-listed):

- `button`
- `fieldset`
- `input`
- `keygen`
- `object`
- `output`
- `select`
- `textarea`

---

"why `<input type="image" src="" />` is not counted?"

Because, historical reasons...

> [...] with the exception of `input` elements whose `type` attribute is in the
>   [Image Button](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#image-button-state-%28type=image%29) state, which must, for historical reasons, be excluded
>   from this particular collection [HTMLFormControlsCollection].